# Forge ModelDerivativeAPI: can't convert to obj format

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm trying to convert *.nwc* file uploaded on my **A360** account with *ModelDerivativeAPI* with [this method](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/). While converting to *svf* and some other formats works for me perfectly I have troubles with converting to *obj* format. I keep getting the following 400 error:

> {
>       "diagnostic": "Failed to trigger translation for this file." }

Here is the body of my POST request:

```
{

    "input": {
      "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLjJFZWM1RzZsU1NXMXNnVmFUSW93Zmc_dmVyc2lvbj0x"
    },
    "output": {
      "formats": [
        {
         "type": "obj"
        }
      ]
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the `advanced` field as follow:

```
{
 "input": {
  "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLjJFZWM1RzZsU1NXMXNnVmFUSW93Zmc_dmVyc2lvbj0x"
 },
 "output": {
  "formats": [
    {
     "type": "obj",
     "advanced": {
      "objectIds": [-1], // -1 means all nodes, otherwise specify an array of valid dbIds
      "modelGuid": "ab2fb5b0-9101-0d3e-28c9-e61f9f0c15c5" // Get this one from the GET :urn/metadata call - https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-GET/
     }
    }
  ]
 }
}
```

You can use my sample [https://oss.autodesk.io](https://oss.autodesk.io/) which exposes a UI to help you test and format the payloads:

[image]

Hope that helps

Comment: Cool! Those fields are mentioned as optional in the doc, but they are actually required. I will point this out so they correct it. Thanks